# SWRevealViewController - managing 2 different left menus

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

So Ive implemented the SWRevealViewController in my app, with much success so far.

A challenge I have now is that I want to accomodate a different Menu based on a different user profile type.

Currently I am able to push a new 'frontViewController' to my 'self.revealViewController' which shows a different main screen, but when I tap the menu button, is reveals the original menu (as sort of expected).

Is it possible to programtically change which menu view controller I want to reveal when I push the new front view controller?

Is it even possible to have a scenario like this using SWRevealViewController? (ie. having 2 different 'rear' views depending on which front view you are using?)

Thanks!

Comment: Create object of `SWReavelController` which is prefer as depend on user, in rear view controller. Now change target of menu button and this will point to menu which you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly possible with SWRevealViewController to change the rear view controller while it is running.

You'll want to maintain a reference to each view controller that you want to show such as

```
var myFirstViewController: UIViewController?
var mySecondViewController: UIViewController?
```

When you want to change them, set the rearViewController property on your SWRevealViewController as in

```
myRevealViewController.rearViewController = myFirstViewController!
```

or

```
myRevealViewController.rearViewController = mySecondViewController!
```